# Query appended to url causes page to jump down

Tags: javascript, query-string

On my page here: http://greenjobinterview.com/win-fiat-hr-tech/ if there is any query string added to the URL, it causes the page to "jump down" halfway. For example: http://greenjobinterview.com/win-fiat-hr-tech/?question. When I disable JavaScript for the page, the problem goes away. I inherited this from another developer. How can I even begin investigate which javascript file is the culprit?

Thanks!

Comment: You will want to search the JavaScript for things like `window.location.search` which references the query string and `scrollTop` which is the jQuery property for animating the scroll position. I peeked at it but there was no clear answer after a couple minutes.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. It turns out it was a bit of code in the footer which was targeting all divs with a class of "content", of which there were many. Sure enough, it was using the "scrollTop". Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer won't be applicable to a lot of people. For my specific problem, the following script was targeting all divs with a class of "content". There were a few, causing the scroll down. Thanks to @Jeff for the tip to search for "scrollTop". Here is the culprit below in case it helps anybody. I changed ".content" to "#content" to affect the ID rather than class of content which fixed it because there was only one ID of content on each page.

```js
            $(function(){
                $("form.biggreenbtn").each(function(){
                    var form = $(this), p = 0;
                    console.log($.parseJSON('<?=$gets?>'))
                    $.each($.parseJSON('<?=$gets?>'), function(i, v){
                        $("[name='"  + i + "']", form).val(v);
                        if(p === 0){
                            $("body, html").animate({scrollTop: form.closest("#content").offset().top - 150 + "px"});
                        }
                        p++;
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I even begin investigate which javascript file is the culprit?

Comment out JavaScript `<script>` tags until the behavior stops.